# Why this USPS Query not working

Tags: xml, usps

I'm using My UserID instead of XXXX. Please see the attached Image
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOn1q.png)

```
https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?
API=CarrierPickupAvailability&XML=
<CarrierPickupAvailabilityRequest USERID="XXXX">
<FirmName>ABC Corp.</FirmName>
<SuiteOrApt>Suite 777</SuiteOrApt>
<Address2>1390 Market Street</Address2>
<Urbanization></Urbanization>
<City>Houston</City>
<State>TX</State>
<ZIP5>77058</ZIP5>
<ZIP4>1234</ZIP4>
</CarrierPickupAvailabilityRequest>
```

Comment: Maybe they are down?

Comment: @litelite I don't think so. I tried to contact with technical support, After explaining everything they said (try to use Internet Explorer)

Comment: Are you sure that this API is using the GET method? Did you try with a REST client (like postman). Sometime browsers will cut down the urls if they're too long

Comment: It seems that the route on which you are trying to do your call is not valid. I tried to copy paste your exemple (with the XXXX as the USERID) and it told me "API Disabled: CarrierPickupAvailability.  This test request is no longer valid. Please use https://stg-secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll"

Comment: @litelite I also tried  stg-secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll with and without https but still no luck

Comment: Is it the same error?

Comment: @litelite no this time i'm getting this <Error>
    <Number>80040B1A</Number>
    <Description>API Authorization failure.  is not a valid API name for XML request CarrierPickupAvailabilityRequest.</Description>
    <Source>USPSCOM::DoAuth</Source>
</Error>        This is Really strange im using examples from their PDF

Comment: And is your PDF up to date?

Comment: Some other part of the PDF are using `USERNAME='your account'` maybe some part of the PDF are outdated?

Comment: @litelite thanks for the helping also pointing out postman i really appiricate. Now I'm using this code             
https://stg-secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=CarrierPickupAvailability&XML=
<CarrierPickupAvailabilityRequest USERID="XXXX">
<FirmName>ABC Corp.</FirmName>
<SuiteOrApt>Suite 777</SuiteOrApt>
<Address2>1390 Market Street</Address2>
<Urbanization></Urbanization>
<City>Houston</City>
<State>TX</State>
<ZIP5>77058</ZIP5>
<ZIP4>1234</ZIP4>
</CarrierPickupAvailabilityRequest>

Comment: @litelite    Now getting this Error -> <Error>
    <Number>80040B1A</Number>
    <Description>Authorization failure.  Perhaps username and/or password is incorrect.</Description>
    <Source>USPSCOM::DoAuth</Source>
</Error>

Comment: @litelite Can you help with this i'm using my userid -> https://stg-secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=CarrierPickupAvailability&XML=
<CarrierPickupAvailabilityRequest USERID="475PACKA6854">
<FirmName>ABC Corp.</FirmName>
<SuiteOrApt>Suite 777</SuiteOrApt>
<Address2>1390 Market Street</Address2>
<Urbanization></Urbanization>
<City>Houston</City>
<State>TX</State>
<ZIP5>77058</ZIP5>
<ZIP4>1234</ZIP4>
</CarrierPickupAvailabilityRequest>

Answer (score 3):

> Now getting this Error ->  80040B1A Authorization failure. Perhaps username and/or password is incorrect. USPSCOM::DoAuth

Contact webtools@usps.gov and include your UserID. They need to enable the Pickups feature for your account.

BTW as of 2019 the WebTools APIs are located at:

- sandbox (use your production UserID)

  - Secure APIs: https://stg-secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingApi.dll
  - Non-secure APIs: http://stg-production.shippingapis.com/ShippingApi.dll
- production (remove the "stg-" part)

  - Secure APIs: https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingApi.dll
  - Non-secure APIs: http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingApi.dll